# Could not unzip uploaded file on creation of Lambda function using python

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to create aws lambda function using python.

Error in Lambda Function

[image]

Function mentioned below is giving error 'Could not unzip uploaded file'

```
def upload_lambda_function(zip_file_name):
with open(zip_file_name) as zip_blob:
#"fileb://"+base64.b64encode(zip_blob.read()),
    lambda_execution_role_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::' + \
        aws_account_id + ':role/' + lambda_execution_role
    aws_lambda.upload_function(
        lambda_function_name,
        "file://"+zip_blob.read(),
        "nodejs6.10",
        lambda_execution_role_arn,
        "index.handler",
        "event",
        description=None,
        timeout=60,
        memory_size=128)
```

aws_lambda.upload_function define inside library boto/awslambda

```
 def upload_function(self, function_name, function_zip, runtime, role,
                    handler, mode, description=None, timeout=None,
                    memory_size=None):

    uri = '/2014-11-13/functions/{0}'.format(function_name)
    headers = {}
    query_params = {}
    if runtime is not None:
        query_params['Runtime'] = runtime
    if role is not None:
        query_params['Role'] = role
    if handler is not None:
        query_params['Handler'] = handler
    if mode is not None:
        query_params['Mode'] = mode
    if description is not None:
        query_params['Description'] = description
    if timeout is not None:
        query_params['Timeout'] = timeout
    if memory_size is not None:
        query_params['MemorySize'] = memory_size

    try:
        content_length = str(len(function_zip))
    except (TypeError, AttributeError):
        # If a file like object is provided and seekable, try to retrieve
        # the file size via fstat.
        try:
            function_zip.tell()
        except (AttributeError, OSError, IOError):
            raise TypeError(
                "File-like object passed to parameter "
                "``function_zip`` must be seekable."
            )
        content_length = str(os.fstat(function_zip.fileno()).st_size)
    headers['Content-Length'] = content_length
    return self.make_request('PUT', uri, expected_status=201,
                             data=function_zip, headers=headers,
                             params=query_params)

def make_request(self, verb, resource, headers=None, data='',
                 expected_status=None, params=None):
    if headers is None:
        headers = {}
    response = AWSAuthConnection.make_request(
        self, verb, resource, headers=headers, data=data, params=params)
    body = response.read().decode('utf-8')
    if body:
        body = json.loads(body)
    if response.status == expected_status:
        return body
    else:
        error_type = response.getheader('x-amzn-ErrorType').split(':')[0]
        error_class = self._faults.get(error_type, self.ResponseError)
        raise error_class(response.status, response.reason, body)
```

Comment: So did you try to unzip the file that's been generated with `unzip`?

Comment: yes tried ....and i can unzip file .....i think ...there is some issue with base64 and utf-8 endcodings .........i dont how to rectify ...

Answer (score 0):

One thing that might be misleading is that boto 2.0 uses an older version of the Lambda API (2014-11-13). The current API (2015-03-31) (which is what you'll see if you consult [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_UpdateFunctionCode.html)), uses a JSON dict in the body, which includes the base64 encoded zipfile as one of its values. However, in the API used by boto2, almost everything is passed via query params and the entire body is dedicated to the contents of the zipfile as a binary blob (no encoding).

Your problem appears to be the fact that you are prepending `"file://"` to the bytes in your zip. In the boto code you posted, the contents of the `zip_function` argument just get blindly passed through to the eventual HTTP request body. You should open `zip_filename` with the `'b'` flag and just pass `zip_blob.read()` to `upload_lambda_function` without modification. (Or, if you notice, the code can handle file-like objects in addition to strings, so you can simply pass `zip_blob` without reading it).

```
def upload_lambda_function(zip_file_name):
    with open(zip_file_name, 'rb') as zip_blob:
      aws_lambda.upload_function(
        lambda_function_name,
        zip_blob,
        "nodejs6.10",
        lambda_execution_role_arn,
        "index.handler",
        "event",
        description=None,
        timeout=60,
        memory_size=128)
```